# Obfuscate Javascript file in docker

Tags: javascript, docker, obfuscation

I have a javascript file to be shared online with the user. I want to obfuscate that file while building in Docker so that anybody on that link sees a obfuscated code. I found many online tools to manually obfuscate but I want some code which can be run while building in docker to obfuscate that file.

Comment: May I ask why though?

Comment: I have to share that JS file with user but not want to share my original code

Comment: They can manually deobfuscate, don't worry. Reverse engineering is a thing.

Comment: It's a fools errand. Deobfuscating JS is [easy](https://www.google.pl/search?q=deobfuscate+js). Code can be easily extracted out of the Docker image. Better learn about licenses.

Comment: Unless you're storing configuration details/passwords in that code _which you shouldn't be doing_, just add a license and share the code.

Comment: Hi all, updated my question. Hope I am more clear now. Please suggest some solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

## Obfuscating Javascript

Several options depending on exactly what you require:

1. uglify.js

   https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS

   Will uglify js and make it much harder to reverse engineer. However this does leave the code exposed, which might be too much risk for you.
2. encrypt the file, using a crypto library. You then have a "key distrbution" issue, but once resolved this can be the best solution.

   List of javascript crypto libraries: https://gist.github.com/jo/8619441

## Uglify using docker

https://hub.docker.com/r/minty/uglifyjs/

This is a "build container" for ugilfy js. `docker run` against a js file and it will mangle it for you.